# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition no longer working in Safari mobile after iOS9 update

Tags: javascript, safari, geolocation, ios9, navigator

I have a web app that has this code for getting the user's coordinates:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
```

But the moment I updated to iOS9 it ceased to work.  I'm not even getting the Safari prompt anymore asking permission to get my location.  Anyone else having this issue after updating to iOS9 and was able to resolve it?

Answer (score 6):

I've noticed this myself and i'm wondering if iOS 9 Webkit has started to prevent this working via HTTP as I know Chrome will be preventing this shortly as it currently throws the following alert in the web console.

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure
>   origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should
>   consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.
>   See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Comment: Chrome has started restricting this since version 50

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling localization in the general settings of iOS. Settings > Localization > Press localization to enable it.
And now it works.

It seems that iOS 9 has disabled localization in the settings, after installing.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running on a mac, you'll need to enable location services for safari: 
[enable location on OSX](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204690)

Comment: It says Safari mobile and iOS