# Geolocation html5 working on web browser but not on iphone browser

Tags: ios, html, firefox, geolocation

I am using the below code to get the lat and long, on the web browser chrome, firefox  I am able to get the location but when i am running the site on IOS safari and firefox I am unable to fetch latitude and longitude.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn on the location service for the browser app.

-Tap the Settings application
-Tap Privacy
-Tap Location Services
-Toggle the switch to On

Comment: Location service is on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720308/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-no-longer-working-in-safari-mobile-afte